# Android how to move XML drawable shape relative to other shapes

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to create a clock type thing. This code does what I want, but I feel like I am doing it wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"/>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="1.5dp"
                android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="25dp" android:left="25dp" android:right="25dp" android:bottom="25dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="1.5dp"
                android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:right="49.25dp" android:left="49.25dp" android:bottom="75dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid
                android:color="#0FFF00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The green tick mark I feel like I should be able to define using a `<size>` tag and be able to position more elegantly than defining the empty space using margins around the `item`.

Comment: if you are doing it in xml, then you have no problem if it gives you what you want. word!